# Continue streaming audio when offline/disconnected for a few minutes?

Tags: cordova, audio, mp3, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I have searched for a few days, and I can't seem find a solution.  I am hoping someone here can point me in the right direction.

I am building a radio iOS application using Cordova/Angular, and I have one mp3 stream (http://mp3lg3.tdf-cdn.com/5593/goo_102004.mp3) that I am playing with HTML5.

I would like to find a way to continue the stream even if the device loses connection for a few minutes, and if the connection returns, to continue streaming normally. At the moment, if I turn off wifi, or turn my device on 'Airplane Mode', it stops the stream immediately.

I am fairly new to the audio world, and hoping someone with experience can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a normal stream with no live content, maybe you can convert it to a byte array (2x speed), and play it back in the normal speed.  A bit complicating to do though.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP progressive streaming works by simply sending data in one continuous stream, while the receiving end plays back the data as it comes in.  The nature of networks is that data comes in chunks, not quite continuously, so the client playing back the audio has a buffer of a couple seconds to survive the periodic bursts of data.

To survive a dropout of a minute, the client would have to receive more than a minute of data in the future.  This is accomplished by buffering a minute of data on the server and then flushing that buffer as fast as possible to the client upon connect.  While it won't get to the client simultaneously, it should get there reasonably fast and then you'll have that buffer which can survive a disconnection.  That is, if your server is a minute ahead of the client and the client with a full 1-minute buffer loses its connection, it can continue playback for about a minute before having to drop out.

This is only half the problem though.  What do you do when you reconnect?  How does the client synchronize to the server?  Unfortunately, there are no public servers doing live HTTP progressive that support a way to synchronize.  I've done some experimenting myself with `Range` headers and what not which works, but requires a custom client.  (VLC does work however...)

You also must consider the reason your audio is stopping immediately.  If you are trying to simulate a network dropout or slow spot by turning on airplane mode, this is not an appropriate test.  The OS disables the network interface, which immediately drops any TCP connections, immediately killing the pipe to the application.  Most applications will stop playing at this point unless they had some additional buffer regardless of the network connection.  In a situation where your network connection quality suffers, rarely is the TCP connection actually dropped... packets are just delayed causing the audio to eventually stop as the buffer runs out.

With all that, there are two solutions depending on your needs:

### Survive cases where network quality varies, TCP connection survives

This is simple.  Increase the server-side buffer that gets flushed to clients.  I usually use 20 seconds.

Note that not all clients will accept such a large buffer.  Some will lower the TCP window size, preventing the server from sending too much audio data.

*(Note:  If you can't figure out how to do this with your existing streaming server, [buffer configuration is available on the AudioPump CDN](http://audiopump.co) which I have created.  It isn't generally available yet, but you can e-mail me at brad@audiopump.co to try it.)*

### Survive an IP address change, TCP connection is guaranteed to be lost

For this scenario, you need a whole new streaming protocol.  [HLS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) is what you want.

HLS works by segmenting your stream which must be requested by several HTTP requests anyway.  Because of this, the client can change addresses (such as going from a mobile network to WiFi) and the stream will still work.

HLS is unfortunately not as well supported by clients, but the server-side is easy.  Any HTTP server will do in most cases.  The encoder is what needs to change, to encode and upload segments.

Comment: Brad, thank you so much for your response, this is incredibly helpful and informative.  I will send you an e-mail now.